# Mount Koa application in different directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa

I have a three koa application and the structure of this these application is like this :

- app.js
- directory app2

  - app2.js
- directory app3

  - app3.js

  i try to mount app2.js and app3.js on app.js using `koa-mount` package but i get an error :

  ```
   var name = app.name || 'unnamed';
          ^
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
  ```

so the question is how to load different koa application as middleware that exists in different directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

according to this [github issue](https://github.com/koajs/mount/issues/13) app2.js and app3.js should be a module so use module.exports and the in app.js require them as a variable and then mount the variable on specific route variable and then mount the variable on specific route